# Water Leaking Out of Top Outer Corner

Tags: bathroom, shower, leak

I recently noticed water collecting next to the tub. After watching closely, I realized it doesn't happen during a shower or bath, and only collects after a shower is complete. At first, we thought that water was seeping in somewhere along spaces in the caulk, so we re-caulked. But it's still happening. The water seems to be starting at top of the tub where I'm pointing to in the picture below.  What could be the cause of this? 
[image]

Comment: "Only after a shower is complete" suggests to me that this is the "spout end" of the tub, and the water draining back from the showerhead to the spout when completed is somehow going astray - or else shower water in general is going astray, but takes long enough to make it out that you only start seeing it after a shower (which might be testable with a very short and a very long shower as tests.) I have had a spout leak at its connection and seep back though the wall that way, mostly on showers.